# Google Places API: Adding a new Place: Java/Groovy

Tags: grails, post, groovy, location

Can't get the POST working? What's wrong?

Note: This works for a GET with autocomplete
GET works without signing the url

1. I'm following the Web services steps to Sign the URL with my "API Key"
   Docs say"client id" still?
   http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/webservices/

2.Try sending the POST data with the signed URL (tried the unsigned signature aswell)

```
def signedUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/json?key=xxxxxkeyxxxxxx&sensor=false&signature=xxxxxxxxxxsignaturexxxxxx"

    String postData = "{'location': { 'lat': '-33.8669710','lng': '151.1958750'},'accuracy': '50','name': 'Google Shoes!'}"

    URL urlPost = new URL(signedUrl);
    URLConnection connection = urlPost.openConnection();
    connection.addRequestProperty("Referer", "http://www.mysite.com");

    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("CONTENT-TYPE", "text/json");
    connection.setRequestProperty("CONTENT-LENGTH", postData.length() + "");
    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
    out.write(postData);
    out.close();

    String line;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
         builder.append(line);
    }

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
       println json
```

Returns a 403
"java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL:"

Simular to the "Java Access"section under they give an example of a GET
http://code.google.com/apis/websearch/docs/#fonje

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok solved.

No signing the URL required

postData string was wrong
should have been

```
String postData = "{\"location\": { \"lat\": -33.8669710,\"lng\": 151.1958750},\"accuracy\": 50,\"name\": \"Google Shoes!\", \"types\":[\"bar\"]}"
```

Comment: A good way to check whether the json is correct is to pass it into https://www.jsoneditoronline.org/. It will pop out the correct json.